# SSL Certificates for Plesk dedicated server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, plesk

We have a dedicated server that is using Plesk 11 and we would like to buy and install a certificate to acheive the following:

1. Remove the 
   "There is a problem with this website's security certificate." error message that we get when any user logs into the plesk admin panel via url like this: `https://000.000.00.000:8443/`
2. Allow SSL FTP for one of the domains.
3. Allow one of the domains on the server to have a secure login área. like: `https://www.domainnamehere.com/login.php`

I am bit confused how this works, Do we need just one certficate to cover the complete server? or do we need one for each domain? If I buy and install one for: `https://www.domainnamehere.com` will it also work for logging into plesk admin like: `https://000.000.00.000:8443/` ? or do I need 2?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You purchase an SSL certificate on a per domain basis and you need an exclusive IP address on the server (so additional IP than the one that hosts the site) in which to install the SSL certificate - all of which can be done via Plesk.

The SSL certificate provider will likely have instructions for Plesk (as well as other common GUI's) specifically on how to install the SSL certificate.

In the example you provide, you would need two separate SSL certificates to cater for that instance.